# SuperToolTip Issue Library not being referenced using Eclipse ADT (Latest Revision)

Tags: android, android-overlay

I've added the library to my dependencies `[Clean then Project > Properties > Java Build Path > Projects tab > Add]` but when I input the required code i get an error. When i mouse over the error it says "Fix Project Setup" but when i click that i get "No Proposals have been found to fix the unresolvable reference to ToolTipView" and then i'm really lost. Can you please help me with setup?